# R: hierarchical ifelse condition with multiple, parallel outcomes

Tags: r

I am looking for an elegant solution to the following problem:

I need to allocate owners to firms based on different matching criteria. These matching criteria are of different quality, hence criteria with weaker quality should only be used if higher quality criteria do not yield results. In my example, all `a` criteria are of the same quality level and of higher quality than `b` criteria.

The following to illustrate my point:

```
firmname <- c("Firm A", "Firm B", "Firm C", "Firm D", "Firm E", "Firm F")
ownermatch_a1 <- c("Owner 1", NA, NA, NA, "Owner 5", "Owner 6")
ownermatch_a2 <- c("Owner 1", NA, NA, "Owner 4", "Owner 5", "Owner 6")
ownermatch_a3 <- c("Owner 1", NA, "Owner 3", "Owner 4", "Owner 5", "Owner 6")
ownermatch_b1 <- c("Owner 1", "Owner 2", "Owner 3", "Owner 4", "Owner 5", "Owner 6")
ownerfinal <- (NA)

data.frame(firmname, ownermatch_a1, ownermatch_a2, ownermatch_a3, ownermatch_b1, ownerfinal)
```

This yields the following table

```
 firmname ownermatch_a1 ownermatch_a2 ownermatch_a3 ownermatch_b1 ownerfinal
1   Firm A       Owner 1       Owner 1       Owner 1       Owner 1       <NA>
2   Firm B          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>       Owner 2       <NA>
3   Firm C          <NA>          <NA>       Owner 3       Owner 3       <NA>
4   Firm D          <NA>       Owner 4       Owner 4       Owner 4       <NA>
5   Firm E       Owner 5       Owner 5       Owner 5       Owner 5       <NA>
6   Firm F       Owner 6       Owner 6       Owner 6       Owner 6       <NA>
```

I now want R to do the following:
1) If any Firm one of the 3 `a` criteria is non-NA, put it as `ownerfinal`. 
2) If there are multiple parallel `a` non-NA, take any of these randomly and put as `ownerfinal`
3) Only if all of these are NA, take `ownermatch_b1` and put as `ownerfinal`.

So in the example above:
Firm A: Pick any of a1, a2, a3
Firm B: Pick b1
Firm C: Pick a3
Firm D: Pick either a2 or a3

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do `as.data.frame(cbind(...))`; you're coercing everything to a matrix and then that to a data.frame, which will sooner or later screw up your variable types. Instead, just use `data.frame` directly, e.g. `data.frame(a = c('foo', 'bar'), b = 1:2)`.

Comment: @DarshanBaral yes that would be also perfectly fine!

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for the suggestion I will edit this in the example.

Comment: `df$ownerfinal <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x){na.omit(x)[1]})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for loops here. `?max.col` is your friend for finding valid cases across columns and picking one at random:

```
tmp <- dat[2:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)), max.col(is.na(dat[2:4])))]
dat$ownerfinal <- replace(tmp, is.na(tmp), as.character(dat$ownermatch_b1)[is.na(tmp)])
dat

#  firmname ownermatch_a1 ownermatch_a2 ownermatch_a3 ownermatch_b1 ownerfinal
#1   Firm A       Owner 1       Owner 1       Owner 1       Owner 1    Owner 1
#2   Firm B          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>       Owner 2    Owner 2
#3   Firm C          <NA>          <NA>       Owner 3       Owner 3    Owner 3
#4   Firm D          <NA>       Owner 4       Owner 4       Owner 4    Owner 4
#5   Firm E       Owner 5       Owner 5       Owner 5       Owner 5    Owner 5
#6   Firm F       Owner 6       Owner 6       Owner 6       Owner 6    Owner 6
```

You could also use `pmax` if you want to take the first valid result:

```
do.call(pmax, c(lapply(dat[2:5],as.character), na.rm=TRUE) )
#[1] "Owner 1" "Owner 2" "Owner 3" "Owner 4" "Owner 5" "Owner 6"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially the `pmax` function works well for me. I like that your approaches are vector-based and do not require loops. Just one question - it takes the first valid result, going through the columns from **left** to **right**, or?

Comment: @Martin - It will always take the 'maximum' value. So 2 beats 1, "b" beats "a", `NA` always loses to any valid value.

Answer (score 0):

```
doLookup <- function(x){
  for(i in 2:5){
    if(!is.na(x[i]))
      return(x[i])
  }
  return(NA)
}

#loop through each record and make assignment
for(j in 1:nrow(df))
   df[j,6] <- doLookup(df[j,])
df
  firmname ownermatch_a1 ownermatch_a2 ownermatch_a3 ownermatch_b1 ownerfinal
1   Firm A       Owner 1       Owner 1       Owner 1       Owner 1    Owner 1
2   Firm B          <NA>          <NA>          <NA>       Owner 2    Owner 2
3   Firm C          <NA>          <NA>       Owner 3       Owner 3    Owner 3
4   Firm D          <NA>       Owner 4       Owner 4       Owner 4    Owner 4
5   Firm E       Owner 5       Owner 5       Owner 5       Owner 5    Owner 5
6   Firm F       Owner 6       Owner 6       Owner 6       Owner 6    Owner 6
```